# WSO2 CEP output event adaptor error

Tags: wso2, complex-event-processing

I am new to WSO2 CEP

I have created the entire flow to read the JMS message and split it using Text formatter. The problem is that when I try to push messages into the queue, it is not able to reach the the output event adaptor. I have a mysql event adaptor and configured it into my event formatter but I keep getting the below message in my log

[2014-02-13 21:20:06,347] ERROR - {ReceiverGroup}  No receiver is reachable at reconnection, can't publish the events
[2014-02-13 21:20:06,352] ERROR - {AsyncDataPublisher}  Reconnection failed for for tcp://localhost:7661

Can someone help me understand what is this tcp://localhost:7661 is all about

Regards
Subbu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tcp://localhost:7661 is the default port to which Thrift(WSO2 events are published). It seems a default event formatter has been created and trying to publish events to that port.

Can you check your list of event formatters and ensure that no event formatters of type WSO2Event are created. This event formatter might be automatically created if you set an exported stream to be 'pass-through' when creating the execution plan.

You can enable event tracing[1] and monitor to determine exactly upto which point the event is coming in your configured flow.

[1] http://docs.wso2.org/display/CEP300/CEP+Event+Tracer

HTH,
Lasantha

Comment: Yes you are correct. A default event formatter has been created but if I delete it, the formatter that I created has become invalid eventhough the stream being referred to is still valid. The error message says that the stream is not available eventhough it is available

Comment: Hi, if the stream is available when you go to the main menu in management console and go to 'Event Streams', and if the event formatter is configured correctly, then the event formatter should become active. Can you share the event formatter config and the [INFO] message printed in the console regarding this?